# Gitorious post-update script to update Bugzilla bugs?

Tags: git, bugzilla, issue-tracking, gitorious

We have an internal Gitorious and Bugzilla setup. I'd like to write some sort of script that is triggered whenever someone pushes a new set of commits that greps for "bug #" in the commit messages and updates that bug number in Bugzilla with the commit message and a link back to the diff in Gitorious.

My searches on the web didn't turn up anything, but I'm hoping I was using the wrong keywords and that someone out there has already done this.

Comment: You probably don't want to switch from Bugzilla, but FWIW Redmine supports this setup, where it will scan your repository and mark issues as closed or fixed.  It will even support syntax like `References #123` and then include that commit in the details for issue #123.

Comment: I would love to switch from Bugzilla, but it's what everyone's used to at work so I've got to work with what I'm given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [GitZilla](http://www.theoldmonk.net/gitzilla/)? (I am the author).

There's a newish mailing list at gitzilla-talk@googlegroups.com

Comment: I did see GitZilla but the sysadmins didn't want to spend the time to figure out how to have the commit hooks work alongside Gitorious's (and wouldn't give me access to try and figure it out myself). Thanks for writing it, though! Looks like a great tool.